# Reliable timing of snippets in F#

Tags: time, f#, performance-testing

I'm wondering if you have any suggestions on how to time fast functions in F# somewhat accurately. I found this function somewhere:

```
let time f =
  let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
  sw.Start()
  let res = f()
  sw.Stop()
  (res, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
```

Which runs a given function only once, and returns the result and the elapsed time. It does however seem to vary a lot when I run it using https://repl.it, which is my testing ground for F# code currently.

To have something to test with, I've compiled some various alternative solutions to Project Euler 6 ([link to code](https://repl.it/B6j6/3)):

```
let square x =
    x * x

let calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquares list = 
    (list |> List.sum |> square) - (list |> List.sumBy square)


let calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV2 list = 
    list 
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x, x*x) ) 
    |> Seq.reduce (fun (accX, accXX) (elemX, elemXX) -> (accX + elemX, accXX + elemXX))
    |> (fun (x, xx) -> x * x - xx)

let calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV3 n = 
    seq { 1 .. n } 
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x, x*x) ) 
    |> Seq.reduce (fun (accX, accXX) (elemX, elemXX) -> (accX + elemX, accXX + elemXX))
    |> (fun (x, xx) -> x * x - xx)

let calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV4 n = 
    let sumN = n * (n+1) / 2
    let sumNN = n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) / 6
    sumN * sumN - sumNN


let n = 100
let myList = [ 1 .. n ]
printfn "Solution to Project Euler 6:"
printfn "  org: %i" (calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquares myList)
printfn "  v2 : %i" (calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV2 myList)
printfn "  v3 : %i" (calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV3 n)
printfn "  v4 : %i" (calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV4 n)

(** My timing function ************************************************)

let time f =
  let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
  sw.Start()
  let res = f()
  sw.Stop()
  (res, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)


let noopFunc() = List.sum [ 1 .. 1000 ]
let euler6org() = calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquares myList
let euler6v2() = calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV2 myList
let euler6v3() = calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV3 n
let euler6v4() = calcDiffSquareSumFromSumSquaresV4 n

let noop = time noopFunc
let org = time euler6org
let v2 = time euler6v2
let v3 = time euler6v3
let v4 = time euler6v4


printfn "Solution to Project Euler 6:"
printfn "  org: %i in %f ms" (fst org) (snd org)
printfn "  v2 : %i in %f ms" (fst v2) (snd v2)
printfn "  v3 : %i in %f ms" (fst v3) (snd v3)
printfn "  v4 : %i in %f ms" (fst v4) (snd v4)
```

When I run it as it stands here I get (only listing the timing outputs):

```
Solution to Project Euler 6:
  org: 25164150 in 0.037000 ms
  v2 : 25164150 in 0.092800 ms
  v3 : 25164150 in 0.049400 ms
  v4 : 25164150 in 0.018700 ms
```

And a second run gives:

```
Solution to Project Euler 6:
  org: 25164150 in 0.034400 ms
  v2 : 25164150 in 0.102300 ms
  v3 : 25164150 in 0.056700 ms
  v4 : 25164150 in 0.016200 ms
```

Just now these seems to be somewhat consistent, but if I change the order of which test I run first and last it can change the timing by orders of magnitude. So please help me find a better or more accurate way of timing executions of smaller code snippets in F# (hopefully at https://repl.it).

The most important aspect for timing the functions is to get the relative time between the run time of the different functions as good as possible. I know and accept that the exact time running any given function on a different platform will vary.

Comment: Anything where the time is < 1 ms is going to be pretty suspect in .Net.  At least try running say 10k times

Comment: @JohnPalmer, I tried running it multiple times, but something went astray then, so if you have some good alternatives on how to do that without side effects, please post an answer

Comment: `[0 .. 10000] |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> f())` would be one way.  You also want to call `f` a few times without measurement to avoid JIT overhead.  There is plenty of good stuff about how to do this in C# out there and I would just translate that to F#.

Comment: @JohnPalmer, You mention the JIT overhead, and that I understand could effect stuff. Do you know if there is some memoization or other effects which might influence timings? Building of lists, sequences, or similar?

Comment: It all depends on the accuraccy you need.  To get this perfect would require pages of answer, there is plenty of good stuff out there for how to do this in C#.

Comment: Honestly? Running a 'correct' benchmark is not a trivial task in JITed, GCed language. I'd personally recommend [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet) to make your life easier and your benchmarks more accurate.

Comment: Anything based on an environment you don't control is going to give unpredictable results.  You would be better off figuring out how to run stuff locally.

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark testing is no simple task.  Visual Studio does have the Performance Profiler, which comes free with Visual Studio 2015 Community.  I find it very useful.  The other nice thing is that you can run your program and interact with it and see how often various code is called, what else it calls and its average time while being executed.

Here is the link for how to get started with it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Here is an image after I run it against a sample F# console application:
[image]

Things you need to watch for are branch optimizations done by the cpu and any repetitive calculations that you are encountering as part of your test and not part of your normal code execution flow.

Here is the code for the sample application:

```
// define the square function
let square x = x * x

// define the sumOfSquares function
let sumOfSquares n = 
   [1..n] |> List.map square |> List.sum

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    for i in 1..100 do
        let s = sumOfSquares i
        printfn "%d" s
    0 // return an integer exit code
```